# How to manage cookies when app service is running behind the application gateway?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-application-gateway

In my ASP.Net Core application, I am using the OpenId Connect authentication scheme with the Azure AD.

The application is hosted on to Azure app service and it is running behind the application gateway of the Azure.

I have configured Application gateway's and app service URL in the Azure AD's reply URL configurations where I registered my application.

When I hit the application gateway's URL it redirects me for the authentication, then I log in using Azure AD Microsft credentials then after successful login it redirects me to Application gateway URL, then I get 500 internal server error, when I check the response header I can see that SetCookie header's domain is the App service URL which is running behind the application gateway and it shows me warning as "This Set-Cookie was blocked because its Domain attribute is invalid with regards to the current host URL"

Any idea how to resolve this issue

Many thanks

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? @amol